# Oboe audio stream format: will the int16_t format disappear?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

In my Android app, I'm using the [Oboe library](https://github.com/google/oboe) to redirect audio samples to the audio output.

According to my tests, in the `oboe::AudioStreamCallback::onAudioReady()` function, it seems that most of the time, the `float` format is used for the audio stream format. But sometimes, the `int16_t` format is used.

Since the `float` format is much more convenient to use than the `int16_t` format, I have some questions about it:

- When are the `float` and the `int16_t` format used? Does it depend on the device? Or maybe on the Android version?
- Is the `int16_t` format still used on recent devices, or is it something that tends to disappear and only used for retrocompatibility purpose?
- If the format depends on the Android version, what is the min Android API version that uses only the `float` format?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify a format in the AudioStreamBuilder then you could get either float or int16_t. Oboe and AAudio will choose a format that is optimal for that platform. Generally float is preferred. But, for example, on some platforms you can only get a LOW_LATENCY input stream if you use int16_t. So it will choose int16_t.

You can determine the format by calling AudioStream::getFormat().

If you do specify a format then you will get that format when you open the stream, if it is supported. OpenSL ES before L (21) does not support float so Oboe on a pre-L device will not open a stream with float format.

The int16_t format will not disappear. We will continue to support it.

Comment: Just to follow up, Oboe version 1.3.0 supports format conversion. If you enable it then it will convert int16_t to float, or vice versa, when needed.

    builder.setFormatConversionAllowed(true);